# Should ECS scale up/down or scale in/out in load test?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance-testing, amazon-ecs, load-testing, autoscaling

I am testing out my website for load test. My app is running on AWS ECS fargate. Ideally in load test should ECS scale up/down or scale in/out or mixture of both?

Answer (score 1):

ECS only supports scaling automatically in/out.